# Parallel and faster evaluation of SELECTing boolean comparing count

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, union, parallelism

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist
(
    id                    NUMERIC(20, 0)                           NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('blacklist_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
    device_id             VARCHAR(512)   DEFAULT NULL              NULL,
    phone_number          VARCHAR(512)   DEFAULT NULL              NULL
);

CREATE INDEX index_phone ON blacklist (phone_number);
CREATE INDEX index_device ON blacklist (device_id);
```

and I want to use this blacklist to see whether a customer with `device_id` or a `phone_number` is inside of it. So my query is:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
FROM blacklist b
         JOIN
     (SELECT id
      FROM blacklist 
      WHERE device_id = :deviceId
      UNION
      SELECT id
      FROM blacklist 
      WHERE phoneNumber = :phoneNumber) filtered_table ON b.id = filtered_table.id
```

Basically splitting the `OR` condition into sub queries with `UNION` to make use of indexes, but I've discovered that we have so many blacklist rows with `phone_number` row filled whereas fewer with `device_id`.

So, I'm looking for a way to parallelize even further so that when a `device_id` match is found, I don't have to keep looking to collect and `UNION` the results of `phone_number` condition (because at that point I already know that my `SELECT` will return `TRUE`) to come up with a greater `COUNT`, since I'm only interested if the row exists or not.

How do I rewrite this query to achieve it? Though I'm mainly looking for a Postgres solution, I'd be interested in finding out what other DBs can do.

Comment: Unrelated, but: why `numeric` for the ID? `integer` or `bigint` would be more efficient.

Comment: I actually copied from an old Oracle schema where the column is defined as `NUMBER(20, 0)` and converted into `NUMERIC`. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like this should really be two separate tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve written the query so that it has to find every matching row, then lookup the row again to count it. You just want an existence test using an `exists` predicate, this will return as soon as a match is found.

See this dbfiddle for a demo https://dbfiddle.uk/Awu5NUrI you can see that the second branch of the `union all` is not executed because it successfully found a match using a quick index check in the first branch.

You don’t need parallelism, you just need to do less work.

```
select 1
where exists 
  (select null
  from blacklist where phone_number = :phone_number
  union all
  select null
  from blacklist where device_id = :device_id
  )
```

Comment: Would on a big table, if `select null from blacklist where phone_number = :phone_number` and `select null from blacklist where device_id = :device_id` execute, do they execute in parallel or synchronously?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Depends on the number of processors you have and workers configured in postgresql.conf - the server is capable of launching parallel workers - run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to check exactly what will happen.

Comment: No matter how big the table is, an existence check using an index is not going to take long enough to benefit from parallelism. We’re talking about 3 IOs per branch, probably mostly served by cache. It would be more effort for the RDBMS to setup additional threads and coordinate them, and all the branches of the `union` would need to be executed as no thread would know if another thread found rows without waiting for it to complete.

Comment: I see, so there’s no way this query return without completing both sides of `UNION ALL`. Because in application layer, if it can, I can measure it does benefit from parallelism, particularly in worst cases/lookups.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral I don’t follow your comment, but to be 100% clear: The code I wrote and demoed in the DBFiddle uses serial execution and stops as soon as it finds a match - and because it’s just doing basic equality checks against indexed columns that is going to be pretty instant, you can see this in the row source statistics that are included. The statistics will be pretty similar no matter how large the table is. You do not need parallelism for performance here as long as you’re just checking existence via equality filters on indexed columns

Comment: @AndrewSayer sorry was not clear enough. A java implementation with a binary search (to imitate an index lookup) on a list of phone numbers and a list of device IDs is significantly more performant when run in parallel (with a method returning without waiting the result of the second binary search if a match is found) than when run sequentially, on a list of ~1m+ entries.

Comment: An index lookup is a lot more performant than a binary search. You’re comparing apples to orchards though. Your query is just searching with one set of values and will be close to instant once rewritten how I’ve done it. If you have a list of sets of values then you can loop them through the rewritten query. You can bulk it out by calling the DB from multiple connections at once, distributing your list of values out. Or you can rewrite the query again to check existence from a temp table (or similar) with your values.